What regex can allow a delimiter, but only if the surrounding groups exist?
I need to design a regex that matches 4 parts separated by a delimiter (: in this case). The 4 parts must be in order, and the delimiter must be present between each part, but the parts are all optional.
These should all match:
A
B
C
D
A:B
A:C
A:D
B:C
B:D
C:D
A:B:C
A:B:D
A:C:D
B:C:D
A:B:C:D

Meanwhile, these should not match.
A:    // cannot end with delimiter
:C    // cannot start with delimiter
ABC   // cannot omit delimiter
A:BC  // cannot omit delimiter
A::B  // cannot duplicate delimiter
...   // many other possible non-matches

My problem is that I don't know how to match the delimiter.

I tried ^(A)?:?(B)?$, but then it will match AB.
I tried ^(A:)?(B)?$, but then it will match A:.
I can manually enumerate all the 15 match types, but that is a big mess (^(A)|(B)|(C)|(D)|(A:B)|(A:C)...........$). In the actual regex, A and B, etc. are more complex.
I tried a more concise enumeration like this ^((A)|((A:)?((B)|((B:)?((C)|((C:)?(D)))))))$, but it looks like a total mess to me still. I'll go with this option if I can't find a better answer though.


Will ABCD always come in that order, I mean no BA?

Yes, always that order.

You can make the colon optional but use word boundaries to require it between letters:
^\b(?::?A)?(?:\b:?B)?(?:\b:?C)?(?:\b:?D)?$

See this demo at regex101 - To allow empty matches, move first \b inside leftmost group.

Or you make all characters optional and use a lookahead at start to validate the format:
^(?=\w(?::\w)*$)A?:?B?:?C?:?D?$

Another demo at regex101 - For empty matches change the lookahead to (?=(?:\b:?\w)*$).
Here a \w is used which is a shorthand for word character and usually matches [A-Za-z0-9_].

A more general idea to accept empty matches is simply attaching |^$ at the end of the pattern (regex101 demo)  or wrap the whole pattern into an ^(?: optional group )?$ (regex101 demo).

The word boundaries do it very nicely, thanks! The resulting regex only contains one instance each of A, B, C, and D, which is really what I wanted.

There's no need to do anything fancy. Just match a letter and a colon 0 to 3 times, followed by a letter:
^(?:[A-D]:){0,3}[A-D]$
https://regex101.com/r/AsjmWQ/1
If order is important, you can invalidate out-of-order matches by using lookaround at the beginning of the pattern, although this approach will quickly lead to complicated patterns if your actual data contains more than 4 possible values:
^(?!.*B(?=.*A))(?!.*C(?=.*[AB]))(?!.*D(?=.*[ABC]))(?:[A-D]:){0,3}[A-D]$
https://regex101.com/r/kdz9xG/1

Question states: the 4 parts must be in order and parts are all optional

Thanks for the idea. But in this case, A, B, C, and D represent complex regexes, so my goal is to not repeat them. I should have made that more clear in the question.
